# Nginx for block attacking requests

Tags: nginx, location

I am receiving requests of this type on my website (I think it's an attack):

```
/name-of-post/==f.charAt(f.length-1))%7Bif(f=f.substr(1,f.length-2),-1!=x.indexOf(f))return%20I=!0

/name-of-post/&&(d=!1,b=b.substring(1));var%20m=b.split
```

**How can I block them to return an HTTP 444 status code?**

Comment: It depends on your backend and what a "nornmal" request look like. Whats a ligit request looks like? Regex based approaches are not really efficient but could work if there are just a specific kind of request you want to block.

Comment: I use Wordpress and the bad requests are usually the same one that I have put.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case you know the kind of URIs and you want to block them AND under the warning that this is NOT! a 100% protection OR WAF (Web application firewall) implementation this will do the trick for the kind of URIs including a sequence of bad characters like `;` `%3B` `charAt` `var`

```sh
  location ~ "(\bcharAt|;|\%3B|var\b)" {
  return 444 "Bad Request\n";
}
```

Be careful adding bad characters. `?` and `+ = .` are legit for example.

A better approach would be the usage of a Web Application Firewall to detect such request and block them. Look into mod_security if you want to learn more about it.